# Array is populated but individual element is undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, supabase

Array is being populated how I wanted it to after formatting some data that I took from a database, but accessing an individual element returns undefined using console.log. I wanted to use this array to pass it to another component that will use its elements, but the component is now blank (I suspect it's because the individual elements are undefined). Hopefully the following code will shed some light on where I went wrong:

```
(async function() {
    const asyncFunctions = [supabaseClient.fetchRecommendedTutors('802201628')];
    const results = await Promise.all(asyncFunctions);
    console.log(results);
    console.log(formatData(results));
   })();

   var tutorsToUse = [];
   function formatData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0]);
    for (var i = 0, len = data[0].length; i < len; i++) {
      const tut = {
        'name' : String(data[0][i].names),
        'specialty' : String(data[0][i].specialty),
        'courses' : [String(data[0][i].course_id)],
        'profile' : "",
        'rating' : Number(data[0][i].tutor_rating)
      };
      tutorsToUse.push(tut)
      console.log(tutorsToUse[0]);
   }
   return tutorsToUse;
  }
  
  console.log(tutorsToUse[0]);
  console.log(tutorsToUse);
```

Doing console.log(tutorsToUse) returns what I expected it to, but console.log(tutorsToUse[0]) does not. What is going on here?

I've tried many different things and been a few hours at it just googling stuff. I have extremely little experience with javascript and asynchronous functions, but I was thrown into this for a college class.

Comment: I used console.log after formatData

Comment: When are they going to be available? Like, I need to use the tutorsToUse array somewhere else. The main problem I'm running into is not even the console.log stuff I just want to know why a component is blanking out after passing that array to it. I don't even know where to begin debugging that, so my first thought was that it might have to do with the undefined individual elements.

Comment: Sorry, @JaromandaX just updated it.

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, my bad. It's back up.

Answer (score -1):

Believe me, you should learn something more about javascript and async function. The simplified code is as below.

`PS: Ignore exception handling`

```
async function requestAndFormatData() {
  const result = await supabaseClient.fetchRecommendedTutors("802201628");

  const tutorsToUse = result.map((item) => {
    return {
      name: String(item.names),
      specialty: String(item.specialty),
      courses: [String(item.course_id)],
      profile: "",
      rating: Number(item.tutor_rating),
    };
  });
  return tutorsToUse;
}

requestAndFormatData()
  .then((tutorsToUse) => {
    console.log("tutorsToUse = ", tutorsToUse);
    console.log("tutorsToUse[0] = ", tutorsToUse[0]);
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error("something wrong", ex);
  });
```

Edited for you question:

> Doing console.log(tutorsToUse) returns what I expected it to, but console.log(tutorsToUse[0]) does not. What is going on here?

`console.log(tutorsToUse)` returns your expected, because `tutorsToUse` is a referenced object in console. It will show your expected value after `tutorsToUse` gotted.

But `console.log(tutorsToUse[0])` will be execute immediately while `tutorsToUse` is an empty array. So `tutorsToUse[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Hmm ok, I need the tutorsToUse array outside of that function though. How can I do that?

Comment: Of cause you have not read this `(async function () {`, and I have explained.

Comment: @Bob the array is being populated as I can see in the console...

Comment: @JaromandaX I have to make it synchronous then?

Comment: @JaromandaX if you replace that last line with 'console.log(tutorsToUse)' the console shows that it's populated with all the stuff that I expected it to have

Comment: @JaromandaX I do not know how a top-level await works, but after searching what it is on Google my code does not have one.

Comment: @JaromandaX Of the code that I put up on this post.

Comment: @yamilmorales just make a function and return `tutorsToUse` . Like I edited.